# DataGrid is too slow on SL4 and SL5 beta when scrolling horizontally

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I've made a simple example which shows low performance of DataGrid on both SL4 and SL5 beta.
As layout root I have

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Then in the code I set:

```
dataGrid1.RowHeight = 30;
dataGrid1.MaxColumnWidth = 200;
dataGrid1.MinColumnWidth = 200;
dataGrid1.RowHeaderWidth = 10;
```

Then I create 50 columns of DataGridTextColumn type:

```
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn {
                Header = "Column "+i,
                CanUserReorder = true,
                CanUserResize = true,
                CanUserSort = true,
                MinWidth = colWidth,
                MaxWidth = colWidth,
                Width = new DataGridLength(colWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel),
                Binding = new Binding(string.Format("C{0}", i)),
            };
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col);
        }
```

And then 100 rows:

```
    private void CreateRows()
    {
        var rows = new ObservableCollection<RowInfo>();
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            RowInfo row = new RowInfo();
            for(int j=0; j<50; j++) {
                typeof(RowInfo).GetProperty("C"+j).SetValue(row, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = rows;
    }
```

RowInfo is a simple object containing properties like:

```
        public string C0 { get; set; }
... till

        public string C49 { get; set; }
```

When I run the app and get the grid it takes my browser tab completely.
But when I scroll it horizontally till the end - it goes too slow and CPU usage is more than 60%.
Scrolling 2nd time goes a bit faster, but still slow.
This is critical for our application.
Do you have any suggestions on how to increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "EnableColumnVirtualization" and/or "EnableRowVirtualization" to true. That's resolved lag issues for me in the past.

Comment: These properties exist on WPF DataGrid, not on SL DataGrid.

Comment: (sorry for delay, family emergency) Hmm, I must have tested this on Telerik's RadGridView then, because I only work in SL.